# XML External Entity Injection (Input Validation and Representation, Data Flow)

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, xmldocument

When I run HP fortify the following code is given as a XML External Entity injection.Problem line is specified as Error Line.Any Help is appreciated.

```
private Document parseXmlString(String stringname, boolean validating) {
        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setValidating(validating);

            ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(stringname.getBytes());


            Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);//Error Line
                return doc;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // A parsing error occurred; the xml input is not valid
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Processing